# Storm KafkaSpout stopped to consume messages from Kafka Topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

My problem is that Storm KafkaSpout stopped to consume messages from Kafka topic after a period of time. When debug is enabled in storm, I get the log file like this:

> 2016-07-05 03:58:26.097 o.a.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: packet_spout __metrics [#object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$TaskInfo 0x2c35b34f "org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$TaskInfo@2c35b34f"] [#object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x798f1e35 "[__ack-count = {default=0}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x230867ec "[__sendqueue = {sojourn_time_ms=0.0, write_pos=5411461, read_pos=5411461, overflow=0, arrival_rate_secs=0.0, capacity=1024, population=0}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x7cdec8eb "[__complete-latency = {default=0.0}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x658fc59 "[__skipped-max-spout = 0]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x3c1f3a50 "[__receive = {sojourn_time_ms=4790.5, write_pos=2468305, read_pos=2468304, overflow=0, arrival_rate_secs=0.20874647740319383, capacity=1024, population=1}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x262d7906 "[__skipped-inactive = 0]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x73648c7e "[kafkaPartition = {Partition{host=slave103:9092, topic=packet, partition=12}/fetchAPICallCount=0, Partition{host=slave103:9092, topic=packet, partition=12}/fetchAPILatencyMax=null, Partition{host=slave103:9092, topic=packet, partition=12}/lostMessageCount=0, Partition{host=slave103:9092, topic=packet, partition=12}/fetchAPILatencyMean=null, Partition{host=slave103:9092, topic=packet, partition=12}/fetchAPIMessageCount=0}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x4e43df61 "[kafkaOffset = {packet/totalLatestCompletedOffset=154305947, packet/partition_12/spoutLag=82472754, packet/totalEarliestTimeOffset=233919465, packet/partition_12/earliestTimeOffset=233919465, packet/partition_12/latestEmittedOffset=154307691, packet/partition_12/latestTimeOffset=236778701, packet/totalLatestEmittedOffset=154307691, packet/partition_12/latestCompletedOffset=154305947, packet/totalLatestTimeOffset=236778701, packet/totalSpoutLag=82472754}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x49fe816b "[__transfer-count = {__ack_init=0, default=0, __metrics=0}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x63e2bdc0 "[__fail-count = {}]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x3b17bb7b "[__skipped-throttle = 1086120]"] #object[org.apache.storm.metric.api.IMetricsConsumer$DataPoint 0x1315a68c "[__emit-count = {__ack_init=0, default=0, __metrics=0}]"]]]
>
> 2016-07-05 03:58:55.042 o.a.s.d.executor [INFO] **Processing received message FOR -2 TUPLE**: source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [30]
>
> 2016-07-05 03:59:25.042 o.a.s.d.executor [INFO] **Processing received message FOR -2 TUPLE**: source: __system:-1, stream: __tick, id: {}, [30]
>
> 2016-07-05 03:59:25.946 o.a.s.d.executor [INFO] **Processing received message FOR -2 TUPLE**: source: __system:-1, stream: __metrics_tick, id: {}, [60]

My test topology is really simple, One KafkaSpout and another Counter Bolt. When the topology works fine, the value between **FOR** and **TUPLE** is a positive number; when the topology stops to consume the message, the value becomes negative. so I'm curious about what causes the problem of **Processing received message FOR -2 TUPLE**, and how to fix this problem?

By the way, my experiment environment is:

> OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)
> Kafka: 0.10.0.0
> Storm: 1.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from the stom mail list I was able to tune KafkaSpout and resolve the issue. The following settings work for me.

```
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 2048);
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_BACKPRESSURE_ENABLE, false);
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384);
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_EXECUTOR_SEND_BUFFER_SIZE, 16384);
```

I tested by sending 20k-50k batches with 1sec pause between bursts. Each message was 2048 bytes.

I am running 3 node cluster, my topology has 4 spouts and topic has 64 partitions.

After 200M messages its still working....

Comment: Yeh, you are certainly right. As throughput is quite important to me, so I just set topology.backpressure.enable as false, then everything works well till now for a couple of hours. It's an key chain of my project. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if the producer is actually writing to the topic you expect.
2. Make sure that the spouts can reach Kafka, at the network level. You         can check it using Telnet command.
3. Can spouts reach Zookeeper? Check it again using Telnet.

Source: [KafkaSpout is not receiving anything from Kafka](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/storm-user/138d0xs4gk/kafkaspout-is-not-receiving-anything-from-kafka)

If above three are true, then:

Kafka has fixed retention window for topics. If the retention is full, it will drop the messages from the tail.

So here what 'might' be happening : the rate at which you are pushing the data to kafka is faster than the rate at which the consumers can consume the messages.

Source : [Storm-kafka spout not fast enough to process the information](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-storm-user/201505.mbox/%3CEA3FFD7F-E302-47F5-93A5-CEAE3C501962@gmail.com%3E)

Comment: Yeah, all three of these conditions are true. Honestly, The consumers is quite fast, and much more fast than the producers in my experiment. but it's worth noting that when the producers work at very low speed, the topology can work properly, however, when I speed up the producers, the problem also comes.

Comment: What's more, when I disable debug in storm, there is no error or warning, when I enable debug in storm, <b>Processing received message FOR -2 TUPLE<b> appears, and the consumer stopped consuming messages, the topology is suspended as well. I'll test more settings of kakfaspout, and thanks for more advice.

Comment: stupig, did you make any progress? I am experiencing the same issue and would appreciate any info.

Comment: @YaRiK Sorry, I have made no progress after debugging this problem for several days. JStorm is an alternative choice. After finishing functionality design, I'll make more test, and keep you informed.

Comment: I posted the same question to stom mail list. Others experienced the same issue. The only reply I got so far is to disable topology.backpressure.enable I am planning to test today. In case you find a solution, please post here.